# What's the maximal dimension of a submanifold that cannot change the embedding dimension of the enclosing manifold?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

This question is prompted by Igor Rivin's comment to [this related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/226923/embeddings-of-punctured-product-of-spheres-into-euclidean-spaces)

For a smooth manifold $M$ of dimension $m$ and a given embedding dimension what's the maximal $n$ such that removal of any $n$-dimensional submanifold $N$ of $M$ from $M$ won't change the embedding dimension of $M$?

The referred to above comment by Igor Rivin shows that unless $M=S^m$ removal of a point doesn't change the embedding dimension. I think one can increase $n$ for larger embedding codimensions.

Here is some handwaving in that direction. Let $d$ be the embedding dimension of $M$\ $N$. Suppose that instead of removing $N$ from $M$ we removed the tubular nbhood of $N$, so we have manifold with boundary $W$ that has interior $M$\ $N$ and is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Let $E$ be the the above tubular nbhood, a $\mathbb{R}^{m-n}$-bundle over $N$. In order to see whether embedding dimension of $M$ remains $d$ we want to check whether it's possible to glue $E$ to $\partial W$ to re-construct $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Suppose now that $m-n>n$. Then $(m-n)$-th Stiefel-Whitney class of $E$ would be trivial and $E$ ought to embed into $\mathbb{R}^{m+n+1}$. Also we need to make sure that $E$ and $W$ can miss each other in $\mathbb{R}^d$, which is always possible when $n+m<d$.

So it seems that for $n<d-m$ one can always $N^n$ from $M^m$ w/out changing embedding dimension of $M$, where $d$ is the embedding dimension of $M$\ $N$.

And here comes the question: can the above be improved for some $m,d$?

Also, does the above estimate holds for subsets $N$ of codimension $m-n$?